# Ranking elements of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am on a function that gives a ranking to each element of an array.
I have already written a function that works well.

```js
var list = [
  {val:10},
  {val:15},
  {val:7},
  {val:21}
  ]

var fun = function (list){
var accum = 1;
list.map(e => {
          e.pos = accum;
          accum++;
          return e;
      });
      list.sort((a,b) => {
        if(a.val > b.val)
            return -1;
        if(a.val < b.val)
          return 1;
        return 0
      });
      accum = 1;
      list.map(e => {
          e.rank = accum;
          accum++;
          return e;
      });
      list.sort((a,b) => {
          if(a.pos > b.pos)
            return 1;
          if(a.pos < b.pos)
            return -1;
          return 0
      });
      
      return list;
}
console.log(fun(list));
```

Is there an other way to code the function instead to do four iterations ?

Thank you

Comment: Where is the error or question?

Comment: your `list.map` doesn't result in anything.

Comment: can values repeat.

Comment: If you run code, you will see each element of array having a rank

Comment: What is the exact parameter of ranking? It'd be better to provide an input and expected output.

Comment: The ranking is based on the attribute val of each element

Comment: I don't understand the reasoning behind this. Your `pos` is basically index + 1. And your rank is just sorting the array by value descending. So if you would clone the array so you can reference the original one and the sorted one seperately, there's not much use in most of this.

Comment: @dz00dz based how, exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take the indices as ranks and sort them. later generate an new object and add the index as rank.

```js
var list = [{ val: 10 }, { val: 15 }, { val: 7 }, { val: 21 }],
    ranks = Object.keys(list).map(Number).sort((a, b) => list[b].val - list[a].val),
    result = list.map(((o, i) => Object.assign({}, o, { pos: i + 1, rank: ranks.indexOf(i) + 1})));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` method in combination with `sort`.

Also, don't forget to use `slice` method in order to sort values for a copy of your given `list`, because `sort` method actions *in-place*.

```js
var list = [{val:10}, {val:15}, {val:7}, {val:21}]
list_sorted = list.slice().sort((a,b) => b.val- a.val).map(a => a.val);
list = list.map(function(item, i){
  return {val : item.val, pos : i + 1, rank : list_sorted.indexOf(item.val) + 1};
});
console.log(list);
```